# Continuous integration for iOS on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, continuous-integration, osx-mavericks

Can I set up the xCode Server instance with a git server, so users can create their repositories and automatically xcode perform continuous integration?

Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are a registered developer, you probably have got mavericks server for free. So you can simply install it, set up git, wiki server and anything you like and configure the xcode continuous integration server by following the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/200-Adopting_a_Continuous_Integration_Workflow/adopt_continuous_integration.html).

Comment: Ok, the problem was some tricks... i had to create some not created directories for xcode.

Answer (score 0):

one small thing that tripped us up was the fact that xcode server could not connect to a 3rd party hosted git repo if the keys had passphrases.

we had to use passphrase-LESS keys to get server to connect.

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

add the new passphrase-less keys in via the server repository settings (allows you to paste in the keys)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would use Jenkins as your CI tool. You can use it both, locally or on the cloud.

On the cloud, you would not need to install/configure anything, as you just need to enable the service you want.

CloudBees provides [iOS builds](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Continuous+Integration+for+iOS) on the cloud. They have a free tier.